# Detecting error 429 while loading a URL

Tags: java, eclipse, url

I am pretty new to Java, and I couldn't find a proper answer to this anywhere, so:
I'm trying to check if the loaded URL can't load because of an error or more specifically error 429 (Too many requests).

I am getting the data from the URL using this:

```
String finalLine = null;
    URL oracle = new URL(url);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        finalLine = inputLine;
    in.close();
    return finalLine;
```

It works very well actually, after that I'm using GSON to parse it.

When it doesn't work the game I'm working on is just crashing. So I would like to code an if function or something that handles the error and does stuff accordingly.

Is there a proper way of doing that? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you mean, you can try checking the response code using `HttpURLConnection#getResponseCode()`.

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://httpstat.us/429"); // url whose response code is 429
HttpURLConnection openConnection = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();

if (openConnection.getResponseCode() == 429) {
    System.out.println("Too many request");
} else {
    System.out.println("ok");
}

openConnection.disconnect();
```

Comment: Get I get the contents of the page using this too?

Comment: Yes. Instead of getting the input stream from the `URL` instance, get it from the `HttpURLConnection` instance using its `getInputStream()` method.